# weka software machine learning

Tags: weka

How to run Weka software on GPU? Weka software uses CPU and does not use GPU at all. I moved the Weka software to the gpu in the Nvidia panel, and I also moved it to the gpu in the PC settings, but it still runs on the cpu.

I moved the Weka software to the gpu in the Nvidia panel, and I also moved it to the gpu in the PC settings, but it still runs on the cpu.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the *GPU acceleration* section of the *Speeding up Weka* article on the Weka wiki:

https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/speeding_up_weka/#gpu-acceleration